# How to call alertDialog in alertDialog?

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I have a alert dialog in android that called from javascript interface.
In alert dialog I have two button that when you click on the one of them I want start other alert dialog that include list.but when I click app crashed.
this is my java code :

```
public void SaveDialog(final String SaveID) {

    final SQLiteDatabase mydatabase1 = openOrCreateDatabase("CopyCollection", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    Cursor c = mydatabase1.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Details WHERE ID="+SaveID+";", null);
    if(c.moveToFirst()) {

        do {

            appName = c.getString(1);
            txtClip = c.getString(2);
            text_Date = c.getString(3);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    AlertDialog.Builder myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidHTMLActivity.this);
    myDialog.setTitle("ذخیره");
    myDialog.setPositiveButton("ذخیره", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            //======================================================
            String names[] ={"A","B","C","D"};
            final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidHTMLActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
            alertDialog.setView(convertView);
            alertDialog.setTitle("List");
            ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AndroidHTMLActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
    myDialog.setNegativeButton("اشتراک گذاری", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String shareBody = txtClip;
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
        }
    });
    myDialog.show();
}
```

and this is logcat :

```
03-24 02:22:58.146    5499-5499/com.exercise.AndroidHTML W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0cf3b20)03-24 02:22:58.156    5499-5499/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.exercise.AndroidHTML, PID: 5499
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Calling View methods on another thread than the UI thread.
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.createThreadException(WebViewChromium.java:268)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.checkThread(WebViewChromium.java:284)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.setLayoutParams(WebViewChromium.java:1618)
        at android.webkit.WebView.setLayoutParams(WebView.java:2099)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3577)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3415)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3391)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at com.exercise.AndroidHTML.AndroidHTMLActivity$MyJavaScriptInterface.SaveDialog(AndroidHTMLActivity.java:198)
        at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript runs on a separate thread other than main thread, which you can't show dialog directly on. Instead, you can show your dialog as following:

First, add a method to your `MyJavaScriptInterface` class:

```
public void showDialog(final String SaveID){
    // create a Handler with the main Looper and 
    // post the dialog showing work to main thread.
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable(){
        SaveDialog(SaveID);
    });
}
```

Then, call showDialog() method instead of SaveDialog().

Comment: where I set this handler?

Comment: @user3001854 In the MyJavaScriptInterface class.

Comment: sorry but I can't fix it,did you explain more or show me some example?

Comment: @user3001854 What do you mean by saying you can't fix it? You don't know how to change the code, or you can change it but still crash? The logcat is the same?

Comment: I don't know how to change

Comment: @user3001854 Just copy my code into your MyJavaScriptInterface class and then replace the call of SaveDialog(saveId) with showDialog(saveId)